# Listing the elements of $A(3)$

Tags: number-theory, permutations

List the elements of $A(3)$ and give the order of each of them.

This is about permutations in number theory ... to clarify that $A(n)$

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using GAP, it is easy to just list the elements of $A_3$. Note that since this structure is a group of order $3!/2$ so it is abelian an of course cyclic. Here you are:

```
gap> G:=AlternatingGroup(3);
                                  Alt( [ 1 .. 3 ] )
gap> e:=Elements(G);
                              [ (), (1,2,3), (1,3,2) ]
gap> List([1..3],k->Order(e[k]));
                                    [ 1, 3, 3 ]
```

Comment: Gap to the rescue!